# What are the main tasks to do when characterizing a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

Suppose you have found in your basement an old small DC motor and you have nothing but the data on the metal plate of the motor because, say, the supplier did not published any techical data sheet. How would an electrical engineer go to characterize such motor, ie what characteristic curves would be a "must have" (possibly independently from the application) for the motor? Please describe also the way you'd go to derive empirically such characteristic curves.

Suppose all you know before starting is just the data on the metal plate of the motor as in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: You measure/test/calculate all the values that you are interested in

Comment: That's a pretty good set of info on the label. A resistance measurement will give you the stall current. So you have Kv, giving you Kt and hence the stall torque.

Comment: Max voltage input and max current input are a very good start, they tell you what not to exceed as you measure for the parameters you want. My usual problem with a totally mute motor is to look at it and say 'hhhhhhh (air being drawn between teeth) that size could probably dissipate two watts', and then creep up on it gently from there.